# how to call a jquery function from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I created a function in jQuery table.js file.

```
function createCookie(name) {
    //...
}
```

how would I call this function from JavaScript in my main.php file? I tried calling it simply like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
createCookie("john");
</script>
```

I have included the table.js file but it's not working! I know that jQuery functions are called via `.changeRows(5)` and for that I have to change my function definition but in that case what object will be associated with this function as I am using this to create cookies!

Comment: make sure table.js is referenced before calling that method.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Not enough information. Is `createCookie` defined in the scope of something else? Are you including your table.js script before you are calling the function? Is it global?

Comment: don't you see @ant: he's missing " after /javascript>

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
createCookie("john");
</script>
```

not

```
<script type"text/javascript>
createCookie("john");
</script>
```

Comment: The 2 snippets in your answer are still not going to work... I'm assuming you meant to add the missing `=` after the `type` attribute!

Comment: uh,.. nothing changed. still missing the =

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there is no such thing as a 'JQuery function'. A jQuery function **IS** as JavaScript function.

For the purposes of your question, however, it looks like you are probably including the JavaScript file in you PHP file AFTER the script block. so when the script block executes, the files hasn't yet been loaded.

You are also missing an `=` after the word `type` in your HTML and a closing `"` after `javascript`

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake....i am including the table.js file before my function call...it goes like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="ui/jquery.table.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">createCookie("john")</script>` but the function call isnt been made.

Comment: Is the function declared within another block of code within the file?

Comment: oh sorry its in the `(function($) { } )` block in table.js...do i need to take it out? if i keep it there(inside the block) then hw am i gona call it?

Comment: Well, firstly, test to see if it works if you put it outside of this block. Personally, i'm surpirsed that it doesn't work from within. Rather than clog up SO with tons of code, can you paste the entire code with your inline function it into JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/), save it and post the link back here

Answer (score 1):

First off all, jQuery is not a language. it's a library for javascript. Hence, you created a javascript function.

Since you're using jquery, just add

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    createCookie("john");
});
```

to the end of your js file

for standard js you could use

```
document.onload = function(){
    createCookie("john");
};
```

Comment: im calling the function in exactly the same way...but its not working!